# PHP gd library imagepng function not overwriting

Tags: php, server, gd

My files are hosted online at A2 hosting. Essentially part of my website creates an image in 'images/$var.png' where $var is passed into the file that creates the image. Later on another php file runs which is supposed to create a new image and overwrite the old one. So it should be something like:

1. Maker1 creates picture of dog, saves it to server.
2. Maker2 changes picture of dog to picture of cat.

Part one of this process works perfectly. The first image is created and saved to the server. However when the time comes for the second image to overwrite it, the function fails. In both cases, I use imagepng to save the file. The documentation says it will overwrite the existing file automatically. However the second version of file is not being saved.

I then tried both unlink and imagedestroy to first destroy the old image from the server. Neither of these work either. Both return "Image could not be removed.". No errors are being shown.

The code is essentially this. File1 contains

```
function update_image($row){
    if(imagedestroy('assets/images/$row[0].png')) {
        echo ("Image destroyed. ");
    } else {
        echo("Image not destroyed. ");
    }
    imagecreatefrompng('assets/images/base.png');

    // image is manipulated
        
    if(imagepng($base, "assets/images/$row[0].png")){
        echo("New image saved. ");
    } else {
        echo("Image could not be saved. ");
    }

}
```

and File2 contains:

```
function image_cron(){
    // mysqli_query gets rows of info
    // loop calls update_image on each row
}
```

File2 is the cron, which is called on automatically. I've tested with echos, and this file is called correctly and links to File1. The function in File1, update_image, is also called properly. On an attempt at replacing an image, "Image not destroyed. " and "Image could not be saved. " are returned on every round of the loop.

Comment: Can you provide some code to help us understand exactly what's happening?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added some code to show what's happening.

Comment: So it's the cron that fails? Which user is the cron run under, and who is the owner and group for the folder which contains the images? `ls -l` is the command you need.

Comment: No the cron works. The file is called, and the functions are called. imagepng does not work and neither unlink nor imagedestroy will destroy an image. I've not changed the default owner of the files so I assume they are run under the owner, myself.

Comment: Basically, you need to check that the initial PNGs when created are owned (or at least in the same group - with write permissions) as the user which runs the cron. It sounds very much like a permissions issue. If, for example, apache runs the first script, the images will be owned by apache, if ubuntu runs the cron and isn't in the apache group, then it won't have write permissions and `unlink` and `imagepng` will fail.

Comment: I notice the public_html folder has a permissions name of nobody while all the files inside including the images have a user of my website name when I run ls -l on them. Do I need to change the permissions name on the public folder?

Comment: public_html should be fine. It's usually owned by nobody (cPanel I think) and in a different group. The cron is run by the user with your website name?

Comment: Yes it is, as is the file it calls on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check the directory permissions. It could be possible that you are providing some specific permissions or the particular directory just have owner right. Otherwise it doesn't seem to have a problem if you are using same function and using same filename including extension.

Comment: Permissions are at 755 right now for the folder in which images are stored.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).